# Specify "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" property with gulp-msbuild

Tags: msbuild, gulp

Continously getting error like

```
Copying file obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll to E:/Webs/Sitecore9/8\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll failed. The process cannot access the file 'E:/Webs/Sitecore9/8\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

While searching for answer it is found that uncheck  "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" property will be helpful.
How it can be done using gulp-msbuild ?

Comment: Please try to set property [nodeReuse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msbuild#nodereuse) to `false`.

Comment: The nodeReuse property is already false